# How to avoid HTML javascript string spacing come with (+) sign?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have create a html form with javascript that must run at IE to trigger outlook by using mailto action, but for the string I pass to outlook, all the spacing auto replace by (+) sign. Below is my code:

```
<script>
var i= 'Product name:';
var idproduct=i.split('+').join(' ')
    function beforeSubmit() {

        var Product = document.getElementById("Product_Name");
        var Email = document.getElementById("Email_Address");
        var body = document.getElementById("body");
        body.value = idproduct+ Product.value +"\n";
      }
</script>
<input name="Subject" size="78" id="Subject" type="hidden" value=" Car Notification" /><br/>
```

But the output I get is :

Subject the email:

```
Car+Notification
```

Body of the email:

```
Product+name:Honda
```

My expected output is without all the plus sign for the spacing.Anyone have ideas in this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could write the mailto link like this to avoid the "+" symbol: `mailto:somebody?subject=etc&body=etc`. We send the subject and body as query parameters. You could check the example below, it works in IE:

```js
function beforeSubmit() {
  var Product = document.getElementById("Product_Name").value;
  var Email = document.getElementById("Email_Address").value;
  var eTo = encodeURI(Email);
  var eSubj = encodeURI("Car Notification");
  var eBody = encodeURI(Product + "\n" + "anotherline");
  var email = "mailto:" + eTo + "?subject=" + eSubj + "&body=" + eBody;
  document.getElementById("myform").href = email;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="Email_Address" type="text" value="somebody@example.com" />
  <input id="Product_Name" type="text" value="enter your message here" />
  <a href="" id="myform" onclick="beforeSubmit()"><input type="button" value="submit" /></a>
</form>
```